# Raspberry SD card port problem

Tags: sd-card

I have problem with my Raspberry Pi 3 b+. I think the SD card slot is broken.

I don't have a monitor, so I am using VNC viewer to remote my Noobs. I installed Noobs on my SD card, but when I plug it into my Raspberry Pi and scan the IP address (I've already make ssh & `wpa_supplicant.conf`) the scanner cannot find the device. But then I tried to plug in my SD card into another Raspberry Pi 3 b+ (my friend's Raspberry Pi) the scanner finds the device.

Is it true that my Raspberry Pi's SD card slot is broken? Or can I find another way to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried the reverse process? Insert your friends SD card in your pi, if it still isnt found, I would suggest plugging a monitor into it, so you can see if there is any boot activity/errors. There are other things that could be the issue(networking cable, Ethernet jack, the mac address is being denied or is corrupt), but seeing it boot on the monitor will at least give you some idea of what is going on, or if its completely dead.

Comment: Well, as soon as you have inserted the CD card,  the red light is on, telling you that power is OK.  What follows is the the little green light blinking, meaning the Rpi is reading the SD card. Now what does the red or green light say? If both red and green light is working, then your SD card slot should be good.

Comment: How did you remote login to the pi and write to the SD card?

Comment: " I am using VNC viewer to remote my Noobs" NOOBS is NOT an OS (it is an OS installer/manager) so it can't support VNC. It can only be used with a keyboard and monitor to install an OS.

Comment: Thnks for the answers

Comment: Thnks for the answers. Im tryin to "re-flash" my os and connect my raspi to a monitor , and find out that my sd card slot was fine and booting process was fine to, turn out the real problem is my raspi can't connect to any wifi, it cant even detected any available network. What can i do ?

Comment: You should make a new question about the new issue.

Answer (score 2):

Answers are given at comments. That's not the right place. I will summarize them here to be on the right place.

Try the reverse process. Insert your friends SD card in your pi, if it still isn't found, I would suggest plugging a monitor into it, so you can see if there is any boot activity/errors. There are other things that could be the issue(networking cable, Ethernet jack, the mac address is being denied or is corrupt), but seeing it boot on the monitor will at least give you some idea of what is going on, or if its completely dead. -*@Chad G*

Well, as soon as you have inserted the CD card, the red light is on, telling you that power is OK. What follows is the the little green light blinking, meaning the Rpi is reading the SD card. Now what does the red or green light say? If both red and green light is working, then your SD card slot should be good. -*@tlfong01*

> I am using VNC viewer to remote my Noobs

NOOBS is NOT an OS (it is an OS installer/manager) so it can't support VNC. It can only be used with a keyboard and monitor to install an OS. -*@Milliways*